# How to limit the number of fetched children in django-treenode

Tags: django, rest

I have a comment Model, where a comment can be a root item or under another comment.
I'm using REST API to get the full tree.
Is it possible to limit its depth, so for example It will stop after 3 nodes from each root comment.
I want to add a "more" feature instead of show the whole tree at once.

`

class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
leaf_nodes = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = [
        'id',
        'body',
        "leaf_nodes"
    ]

def get_leaf_nodes(self, obj):
    return CommentSerializer(obj.get_children(), many=True).data
```

`

I tried looking at the documentation on GitHub but didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is at DRF level. You should try to set `depth` parameter for your serializer. From the doc:

> The depth option should be set to an integer value that indicates the
> depth of relationships that should be traversed before reverting to a
> flat representation.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization

Comment: I set depth inside "class Meta" of the serializer to 1 and 2, however the response doesn't change.
It is something to do with "obj.get_children()". The problem is that there is no parameter to limit the depth of the travel down per each branch.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found out that I can use the `obj.tn_level` to check the depth level of the item.
I used two Serializers.
The first one is for the first round, where I limit the tn_level based on a const in settings.
The second Serializer, uses a parameter I pass via context from the view to the Serializer, containing the level of the last leaf on the display and via another const from settings I fetch more nodes.

This way I show part of the nodes and via pressing "more" I load a few nodes each time.